# Make a second column's values the same, for multiple rows matched by a first column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

A subset of my Excel data sheet contains names in different rows (the same name can appear multiple times) and a corresponding number (`1` or `0`, but if someone has a `1` after their name, it only appears once).

For example I could have `Robert` appearing in my first column four times, then in a different column it may have three `0`s and one `1`. Below `Robert` I could have `John` appearing multiple times with all `0`s. Then another name etc.

What I would like to do is if a person has a `1` in that other column, all of the entries for that person in that column should be changed to a `1`.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Since I have over 35k entries, it would be a drag to check them manually.

Comment: You mean to say that Column A has Robert 4 times & Col B has 3 zeros and b4 has 1, in that case you are expecting remaining 3 zeros in Col B should replaced with 1 !!

Answer (score 1):

Example.

Column A contains Names. Column B contains Numbers.

Edit C1 with formula

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)
```

Copy this formula to whole column C (select C1, Copy, select all cells in column С in data range rows, Paste).

To make this data static, use Copy - PasteSpecial - Values.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add an additional column, then you can use a formula to do the changes. Otherwise you will need to use excel vba and this may be quite complex. My way of doing this would be similar to the method proposed by @Akina with a small change. Consider my spreadsheet in the image:

[image: Initial Table]

Now go to column C and add a heading (if you want) and include and include the formula:

```
=IF(SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)>0,1,0)
```

in cell C2. Copy and paste this in all the cells in column C.

[image: Updated Table]

Thats it! Note that blanks in column B will be equivalent to 0's.

Comment: Using IF do not allow to see wrong groups containig more than one 1's whereas those error detection can be useful.